# How can I join the points of a plot whose data contains gaps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, subplot

I'm trying to join the points of a plot with at least 70 subplots, since it is not a scatter (because I can't use it since they are not series), I've tried marker = 'o-', but doesn't work. The data is in the format %mm-%yy, there are at least 6 different months (as a date column), and not for every column (Fund names) there exist any data in an specific month, however I want to join all the points from the same column even if they skipped any date.

I'm trying this, however it only joins the data that corresponds to following months.

```
df.plot(subplots = True, figsize = (20,20), layout = (14,5),legend=False,marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: Drop the `NaN`s in between the populated points

Comment: Hi @ SilviaRodenasVaquero, can you provide us with the first few points or some random of your data ? See [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for more tips on how to improve your question − that really makes it easier for other users to give you an answer.

Comment: Hi, I think I finally got it, I only needed to add to my formula .interpolate().plot(...). Thank you anyways!